# Is there a way to bundle typescript lambda that is using external modules and pass to cdk lambda.Code.fromAsset

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Im new to AWS CDK and I'm trying to find a way to build a lambda written in typescript that uses external modules (non-aws modules).

When the function is built (bundled) I will pass it to

```
new lambda.Function(scope, "Function", {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('path/to/the/bundled/asset'),
        handler: "index.handler",
        environment: {
          ......
        },
      });
```

I read I can use docker container for this purpose, but this is not an option for me.

Comment: Why isn't docker an option? The alternative is to use any other means to package the code, so that the path to the asset contains the complete lambda package, including dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NodejsFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html) takes care of bundling for you. It can use `esbuild` instead of Docker, if installed. It automatically bundles dependencies according to your imports. Those dependencies should be in your `package.json`. You should put `esbuild` in your `devDependencies` to make sure it's always used.

For example:

```
new lambda.NodejsFunction(this, 'MyFunction', {
  entry: '/path/to/my/file.ts', // accepts .js, .jsx, .ts, .tsx and .mjs files
  handler: 'myExportedFunc', // defaults to 'handler'
});
```

You can also use the shorthand syntax. You would have to name your Lambda code file as `my-construct.api.ts` assuming you pass `api` as the Lambda id and assuming you use this in `my-construct.ts`.

```
new lambda.NodejsFunction(this, 'api');
```

Here is a sample directory structure for the second option:

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── my-construct.api.ts # Lambda handler for API
│   └── my-construct.ts # CDK construct with one Lambda function
├── package-lock.json # single lock file
├── package.json # CDK and runtime dependencies defined in a single package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bundler to convert your ts code into one bundled js file that includes all your lambda code and dependencies.

very common bundlers are:

1. webpack [example](https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/webpack-tutorial-for-beginners/) ([official website](https://webpack.js.org/))
2. es build [example](https://blog.logrocket.com/getting-started-esbuild/) ([official website](https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/))